# Trying to manage Raku's $*REPO at runtime

Tags: repository, raku, code-documentation

Duplicating the behavior of `FindBin::libs` in Perl 6.

```
  (1) Start from `$Bin`.
  (2) Search for `./lib` dir's above it.
  (3) prefix them to the search list.
```

In Raku, this requires managing `$*REPO`, which I think requires using `CompUnit::RepositoryRegistry`, but I cannot find any doc's for it on modules.perl6.org (probably because it is core) or docs.perl6.org.

Q: Is `CompUnit::RepositoryRegistry` the correct thing to be using to prefix some new directories to the list managed by `$*REPO`?

Q: If so, where is `CU::RR` documented?

Q: If not, what should I be using?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Looking for a `lib/` folder will only work with `CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem` repos -- it will not work with `CompUnit::Repository::Installation` repos ( installed modules ).

That being said the following is possible:

```
~/repos/rakudo$ raku -e '\
    say $*REPO.repo-chain.grep(* ~~ CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem);\
    my $lib = CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem.new(prefix => $*CWD.parent.absolute);\
    CompUnit::RepositoryRegistry.use-repository($lib);\
    say $*REPO.repo-chain.grep(* ~~ CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem)
'
()
(file#/Users/ugexe/repos)
```

I'm not sure how wise it is to modify `$*REPO` outside of compile time though. I'd expect some significant precomp penalities at the very least. If it doesn't have to be runtime then the following is an option:

```
~/repos/rakudo$ raku -e '\
    BEGIN say $*REPO.repo-chain.grep(* ~~ CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem);\
    BEGIN my $lib = $*CWD.parent.absolute;\
    BEGIN use lib $lib;\
    say $*REPO.repo-chain.grep(* ~~ CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem)
'
()
(file#/Users/ugexe/repos)
```

Comment: FindBin lib is normally use-ed. The point is being able to locate local filesystem modules at compile time (hence the lower-case module name: it normally functions as a pragma). For non-core modules there needs to be some way to affect the inclusion of modules for local content, for testing and development if nothing else. Q: Given that CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem is not available via modules.perl6.org, where might I find the documentation for it?  Thanks

Comment: Aside: The distinction here is modules on paths not compiled into perl6 or available via PERL6LIB when perl6 was invoked. The addition is compile time in the sense of a use, runtime in the sense of being included by the running perl6 program not compiled into perl6 executable.

Comment: It is not documented, hence its lack of inclusion on modules.perl6.org . For non-core, non-installed modules that need "to affect the inclusion of modules for local content" -- one can already do this explicitly via `use lib $?FILE.parent(2).add("lib")`.

Comment: Could this be achieved by: "use lib $*PROGRAM.dirname.IO.add("../lib/")"?